# How to select the tag based on tag name and get its count

Tags: vb.net, xpath, xmldocument

Not able to select the node with the tag name.

Smaple XML:

```
<author-group id="a001">
<author id="aa001">
  <given-name id="g001">Name</given-name>
  <surname id="s001">Name</surname>
</author>
<author id="aa002">
 <given-name id="g002">Name</given-name>
 <surname id="s002">Name</surname>
</author>
<author id="aa003">
   <given-name id="g003">Name</given-name>
   <surname id="s003">Name</surname>
</author>
</author-group>
```

Code tried:

```
Dim xDom As New Xml.XmlDocument
xDom .LoadXml(XMLStr)
Dim Lst As XmlNodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("//author")
Dim NodeCount as Integer =Lst.Count()
```

The count is coming as zero..

Comment: Is this the whole XML document, or just an extract?  I wonder if the document has any namespaces defined `xmlns` attributes.

Comment: No this is not whole XML document. Yes it has some namespaces in other elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xmlns` attribute defines so called default namespace that applies to all content under the element on which the element occurs.  However, your XPath does not specify any namespaces which means that it will only find `author` elements that are not in any namespace.  You are therefore effectively looking for a wrong element name.

XPath queries that use namespaces require a `XmlNamespaceManager` that provides a mapping of namespace prefixes to namespaces.  It is also possible to use default namespaces in the XPath in the same way as follows.

Substitute the default namespace URI for `xxx` in the following snippet, and execute this after loading `xDom` with your document:

```
'Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces.
Dim nsmgr as XmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDom.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "xxx")

Dim nodeList as XmlNodeList 
Dim root as XmlElement = xDom.DocumentElement
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//author", nsmgr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a new project and it worked correctly.  Here's the code from my test project:

```
Dim XMLStr As String = "<author-group id=""a001""><author id=""aa001"">  <given-name id=""g001"">Name</given-name>  <surname id=""s001"">Name</surname></author><author id=""aa002""> <given-name id=""g002"">Name</given-name> <surname id=""s002"">Name</surname></author><author id=""aa003"">   <given-name id=""g003"">Name</given-name>   <surname id=""s003"">Name</surname></author></author-group>"
Dim xDom As New Xml.XmlDocument
xDom.LoadXml(XMLStr)
Dim Lst As XmlNodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("//author")
Dim Cnt As Integer = Lst.Count()
```

So, your error must be somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (adding the xml DTD, and using XDocument):

```
Dim x As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                             <author-group id="a001">
                                 <author id="aa001">
                                     <given-name id="g001">Name</given-name>
                                     <surname id="s001">Name</surname>
                                 </author>
                                 <author id="aa002">
                                     <given-name id="g002">Name</given-name>
                                     <surname id="s002">Name</surname>
                                 </author>
                                 <author id="aa003">
                                     <given-name id="g003">Name</given-name>
                                     <surname id="s003">Name</surname>
                                 </author>
                             </author-group>

Dim xDom As New XmlDocument
xDom.LoadXml(x.ToString())
Dim Lst As XmlNodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("//author")
Dim Cnt As Integer = Lst.Count()
```